# How do I remove all subviews in Rubymotion?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Basically, I have a quiz app where I add have questions, then switch to a different screen to show an expanded version of the correct answer after it is chosen. I've tried adding button and labels, but when I do this, I eventually end up with buttons and labels 'ghosting' on the screen, after I went them gone. How can I remove all subviews, so that each button and label I add from within a method appears on a fresh screen?

```
class MyApplicationController < UIViewController

def loadView  
    self.view = UIImageView.alloc.init  
end

def viewDidLoad  
    super  
    view.userInteractionEnabled=true  
    @question_index=0  
    @answerChoices = []  
    @questionChoices=["What is best in life?",...]  
    makeQuestion  
end  

def makeQuestion 
    left =20  
    top=100  
    label = UILabel.new  
    label.text =@questionChoices[@question_index]  
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter  
    label.textColor = UIColor.redColor  
    label.frame = [[20,20], [view.frame.size.width-40, 40]]  
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap  
    label.numberOfLines = 0  
    label.sizeToFit  
    view.image = UIImage.imageNamed('background.jpg')  
    view.addSubview(label)  
    4.times do |i|  
        @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)  
    @button.setTitle(@answerChoices[i][@question_index], forState:UIControlStateNormal)  
        @button.frame = [[left, top], [view.frame.size.width - left * 2, 40]]  
    @button.addTarget(self, action:'actionTapped:', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)  
        @button.tag=i  
        top+=45  
        view.addSubview(@button)  
    end  
end

def makeAnswer  
    @button.removeFromSuperview
    @button.removeFromSuperview
    @button.removeFromSuperview
    @button.removeFromSuperview
    view.image = UIImage.imageNamed('back.jpg')
    label = UILabel.new
    label.text =@rightArray[@question_index]
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter
    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor
    label.frame = [[20,20], [view.frame.size.width-40, 40]]  
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap  
    label.numberOfLines = 0  
    label.sizeToFit  
    view.addSubview(label)  


    @button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)  
    @button.setTitle("More questions", forState:UIControlStateNormal)  
    @button.tag=1  
    @button.addTarget(self, action:'makeQuestion', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)     
    @button.frame = [[20, 100], [view.frame.size.width - 20 * 2, 40]]  
    view.addSubview(@button)  
end 

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an array of buttons.  In your `4.times` loop, you are overwriting the instance variable `@button` four times.  Instead, make @button an array of buttons, and assign a different button to each index.

If you have a variable `myView` and want to remove all of its subviews, I believe this will work:

```
myView.subviews.each {|sv| sv.removeFromSuperview}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to tell you how to delete all subviews of an object in RubyMotion.  Since you're new to StackOverflow, if you find this answer correct, press the up arrow above the number to the left and select the check mark to indicate a correct answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the answer (I didn't know I could) and pressed the up arrow, though my reputation is too low for me to vote up.